# Clear property when restart server with springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I create one controller to add/remove a item from my cart, so

```
List<PedidoCertidao> indicadores_session = new ArrayList<>();
```

then I create 2 methods one to add and other to remove:

```
@PutMapping(value="/pedido/add/")
    public void pedidoCertidao_Adicionar(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody PedidoCertidao pedidoCertidao){
        this.indicadores_session.add(pedidoCertidao);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value="/pedido/add/")
    public void pedidoCertidao_Remover(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody PedidoCertidao pedidoCertidao){
        this.indicadores_session.remove(pedidoCertidao);
    }
```

This works fine. but if I restart my tomcat I want to restart the indicadores_session, he is keeping the values

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a shutdown hook. Which mean your hook is called before the server goes dowm. This can be done using `PreDestroy`

Just write this method in in your controller class.

```
@PreDestroy
public void clearSession() {
   indicadores_session .clear();
}
```